# Recipe to get Missing At Random (MAR) data from Not Missing At Random (NMAR) data (find the trick)

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, bias

Data are missing at random (MAR) when " missingness can be fully accounted for by variables where there is complete information" (cf Wikipedia)

It is believed that MAR data make it possible for you to learn from them while  Non MAR data are biased.

So, for instance, in a survey, if you ask an optional question Q1 about the political orientation, you probably won't get MAR data.

No, imagine that you ask the mandatory question Q2 "Would you accept to tell us your political orientation ?" and collect the answer to the previous question only in case of a yes answer to this one.

Then, magically, you get MAR data, because propensity for Q1 to be missing is related to Q2 that is observed.

So now, do I have a data set from which I can learn unbiased model ?

Well, of course the data has not changed, it is still biased. But, that means definition of MAR is not sufficient to grant an unbiased learning.

Intuitively, I would say that we must add the fact that the probability to observe some data (that depends on the already observed data) should be strictly positive.

Is there some reliable work on that subject ?

Comment: The example you gave here is not really purely NMAR or purely MAR. It would be NMAR if a person didn't answer because of their orientation, not simply because people usually don't answer the question. Actually, if people of any political orientation are as likely to abstain from answering, this would be MCAR. Also, by adding Q2 you don't add any new info. This wouldn't remove any biases.